# RelativeLayout Not displaying an image

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

Ok, so here is where I sit: I cannot for the life of me figure out why the image to the left will not display. It should be the same image as the one to the right of notifications. I have gone over it a few different ways and cannot get that image to display on the left side of notifications.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@id/notificationCart"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_expanded_notification_category_height">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/latestNotificationText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/tw_close_handle_height"
                android:src="@drawable/tw_quick_panel_plnm_setting_dv"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <TextView
                android:textSize="@dimen/status_bar_expanded_notification_category_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/notification_category_color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@id/latestNotificationText"
                android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
                android:paddingRight="10.0dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/status_bar_latest_events_title"/>

        <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/latestNotificationText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/tw_close_handle_height"
                android:src="@drawable/tw_quick_panel_plnm_setting_dv"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I know the formatting is terrible... I am modifying Samsung code

Answer (score 0):

If you need to place two images left and right of  the TextView 
why do you need the RelativeLayout?

```
 <LinearLayout  android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ....>
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView      
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <ImageView       
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <LinearLayout />
 <LinearLayout />
```

Note that the parent FrameLayout has it's width set to match_parent.

Comment: I need the RelativeLayout for centering purposes. I went through a ton of LinearLayout models to get it, and it wasn't happening.

Comment: I guess you need to horizontally center the Image-TextView-Image group of views, right?

Comment: Exactly. What I am shooting for is to center the TextView and then toRightof and toLeft of the image, so that it displays centered in both portrait and landscape.

Comment: Then check my updated answer, since this is how I would go about doing that. Take a look at the layout_gravity items. Hope that helps.

Comment: Man, I will give that a shot. I have been doing this for ages now and still can't get it right. Will report back in a bit

Comment: No dice @Plato... java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout

Comment: This error doesn't have to do with the layout file. Please check again where you use the id of the FrameLayout beacause you are trying to cast it to a LinearLayout.

Comment: Check my updated answer, I changed the base `FrameLayout` to a `LinearLayout` to avoid the cast problem. Be sure to set its orientation to `vertical` though.